# How can I get a child element value when rendering in React?

Tags: reactjs

I would like to automatically insert a `value='foo'` property onto an option element so that I can easily select the option from a saved state if the element re-renders.

Currently I can add value manually and it works but I tried to automate this when rendering the children like this. However I can't find the value. Any ideas?

```
// form.jsx
<Select
  label='Select a thing'
  name='things'
  updateForm={update}
  formState={fstate}>

    <option>Foo</option>
    <option>Bar</option>
    <option>Baz</option>
</Select>


// Select.jsx

Select = React.createClass({

  // pass this.name down to this.props.children manually
  renderChildren: function () {
    return React.Children.map(this.props.children, function (child) {
      debugger
      // can't find "foo", "bar" here
      return React.addons.cloneWithProps(child, {
        name: this.props.name,
        value: (get child value)
      });
    }.bind(this));
  },

  handleChange(e) {
    var value = e.currentTarget.value;
    // save to db and save to formState
    this.props.updateForm(this.props.name, value);
  },

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <label>{ this.props.label }</label>

        <select
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          defaultValue={ this.props.formState[this.props.name] }>

          { this.renderChildren() }
        </select>
      </div>
    );
  }

});


// render this HTML

<div>
  <label>Select a thing</label>

  <select class="form-control" >
    <option name="thing" value="foo">foo</option>
    <option name="thing" value="bar">bar</option>
    <option name="thing" value="baz">baz</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Children of the `Select` element are a list of `option`, for retrieve the values inside you simply have to check on the children of each element.

```
return React.Children.map(this.props.children, function(child) {
  // can't find "foo", "bar" here
  return React.addons.cloneWithProps(child, {
    name: this.props.name,
    value: child.props.children
  });
}.bind(this));
```

If the content of the option is only a text you can access it directly with the `child.props.children` attribute.

Eg.

```
<option>Bar</option>
```

If the content is more complex (the option shouldn't have any html tag inside, but maybe for some reason you need it) you have to check the value and add some logic

```
<option>Foo <span>bar</span></option>
```

with a simple `console.log(child.props.children)` you can see the struct of the child element.

Comment: Ah, so simple! Thanks Davide!